# Difference between closed and formclosed event

Tags: .net, winforms, events, lifecycle

Just wondering whats the big difference between `Form.Closed` and `Form.FormClosed` event in the [order of events of Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I've read it in MSDN documentation but still couldn't find anything much different from one another. Please explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closed#remarks):

> The `Closed` event is obsolete in the .NET Framework version 2.0; use the `FormClosed` event instead.

I don't think you should even consider using this event. It's deprecated and hidden but it's there only for compatibility with old source code.

It has the same meaning of the `FormClosed` event but with one (not so much) subtle difference, as you can see on MSDN the `Closed` event isn't raised when application exists because of a call to `Application.Exit()` but the `FormClosed` is.

This behavior is also documented in the link above:

> The `Form.Closed` and `Form.Closing` events are not raised when the
>   `Application.Exit` method is called to exit your application. If you
>   have validation code in either of these events that must be executed,
>   you should call the `Form.Close` method for each open form individually
>   before calling the `Exit` method.

Comment: But in the link I mentioned its shown as one of the events to be raised in VS2010 version.

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani yes, of course it's still there because 100k applications are using that event and to remove it may break tons of code. It's hidden and marked as obsolete primary for new applications but I don't think it'll be removed soon (or it won't be removed at all, I guess WinForms won't evolve more).